# Efficient visualization of categorical data across multiple samples and categories in R

Tags: r, categorical-data, ggplot2, data-visualization

Assume a categorical variable (with states `m`, `o` and `z`) that can be measured for a set of 20 different categories (`c01`, `c02`, ..., `c20`) in a sample. Further, assume that a dataset of six different samples (`s01`, `s02`, ..., `s06`) was generated. Finally, assume that variable state `z` indicates that the respective category cannot be measured in that sample. The data looks something like this:

```
c01    m   o   z   ...   m
c02    o   o   m   ...   o
c03    z   o   z   ...   m
...    .   .   .   ...   .
c19    z   m   o   ...   m
c20    m   o   m   ...   o
     s01 s02 s03       s06
```

What type of plot would you use to visualize this dataset in R, if the objective of such a visualization is to emphasize the differences between states `m` and `o` across samples? (The differences within a sample are of lesser importance.)

For example, I could imagine a graph in which the states `m` and `o` have explicit fields. Please note that s01 has no letter for c03 in the graph below, because that field has a `z` in the table above. Likewise, s01 has no letter for c19.

```
Title   M O   M O   ...
  c01   m       o   ...
  c02     o     o   ...
  c03           o   ...
  ...    .     .    ...
  c19         m     ...
  c20   m       o   ...
        s01   s02   ...
```

However, other visualizations are possible as well. What would the data visualizers among us consider the most efficient visualization? (Since this is a quick exploratory data analysis, any graph easily implemented via an existing R function would be preferable.)

**EDIT 1**: Below please find example input data.

```
dput(inD, file="inD.tmp")
structure(list(s01 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("m", 
"o", "z"), class = "factor"), s02 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L
), .Label = c("m", "o", "z"), class = "factor"), s03 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("m", "o", "z"), class = "factor"), s04 = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("m", "o", "z"), class = "factor"), s05 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("m", "o", "z"), class = "factor"), s06 = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("m", "o", "z"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("c01", 
"c02", "c03", "c04", "c05", "c06", "c07", "c08", "c09", "c10", 
"c11", "c12", "c13", "c14", "c15", "c16", "c17", "c18", "c19", 
"c20"))

> inD
    s01 s02 s03 s04 s05 s06
c01   o   o   o   z   o   o
c02   o   o   o   z   o   z
c03   z   o   z   z   z   z
c04   z   z   o   z   z   z
c05   o   o   o   o   o   o
c06   z   z   z   z   z   o
c07   o   z   o   o   z   z
c08   o   o   o   o   o   o
c09   o   o   o   o   o   z
c10   z   o   o   o   o   o
c11   o   o   o   o   z   z
c12   z   z   o   z   z   z
c13   o   o   o   o   o   o
c14   m   m   m   m   m   m
c15   m   z   z   z   z   z
c16   z   m   m   m   m   z
c17   z   z   z   z   z   m
c18   z   m   z   z   z   z
c19   z   m   z   z   z   m
c20   o   o   o   o   o   o
```

Comment: @StephanKolassa Post has been edited to include example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have given us the data, but there's no context to them. Are they genotypes? Are they endorsements on an ordinal 3 point scale for a 6-item survey?

The most general answer would be to create a mosaic plot. The plot allows the user to (very tediously) evaluate the conditional and marginal probability for any event in the table. It's the default `plot.table` method. I have never personally used such a plot, it's too busy to be useful.

If you are able to identify outcomes and exposures, it's much better to show conditional probabilities of outcomes over all combinations of stratification variables.

If $z$ represents a missing state, you can calculate the above table(s) using a complete case analysis.